# How can I get post-javascript version of AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get data retrieved via AJAX from a page that uses PHP/JS to remove MS Word's atrocious code soup from pasted data in a `contentEditable`.

I've already written the "strip script", but now I'm a bit confused as to how to retreive the post-processed code. Right now it's returning the PHP processed part, but not the complete (JS) processed version.

Is there any way to wait until it's completely finished and return *that* data, or will I have to retrieve the PHP processed portion then use JS on the results received from AJAX?

Psudo-code:

```
//intercept PASTE function
//AJAX passing paste data to 'strip-word-markup.php'

/* [strip-word-markup.php] uses document.write() to replace 
    existing page (not sure if this approach will work or not) */

//Ideally, return PHP/JS processed code and "paste" into contentEditable
```

There isn't really much code relevant to the question, other than the 250 lines it took to clean up Word's formatting, returning clean HTML, and the AJAX call to retreive it.

**Looks like there's no way to wait for JS to execute.** I'll just convert the PHP portion over to JS and put it all in an external .js file. Same thing only different I guess. Thanks!

Comment: some code/pseudo-code will be helpful..

Comment: Without code, it is usually hard to guess what the exact problem is, and guessing for answers is usually the only thing anybody can do. If you provide a piece of code of your previous attempts, it will be a lot easier to understand what the exact problem you're having is. That piece of code can even be code that doesn't work at all, because it would still give a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: From what you are describing it sounds like you are trying to use JS on an AJAX page? The JS wouldn't run, only the PHP as it runs on the server and JS is client side. You would need to run the JS on the results received from the AJAX call.

Comment: @Styphon That's what I was afraid of. It took around 250 lines of code to clean up that nasty Word formatting, I was just hoping to make it an external module instead of adding into my other coding.

Comment: @kcdwayne Look at making it a JQuery function. That said, I've not met much you can achieve in JS that you can't achieve in PHP if you're making an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP script is needed to complete the "cleaning" process then you will have to post the pasted user data to the script and wait for a response like so:

```
$.post('path/to/script.php', {postkey: userdata}, function(data) {
    // access returned php data and do stuff with it here
    // maybe $('textarea').val(data); to replace m$ format with cleaned format
}
```

and in your PHP script just access the posted input with `$_POST['postkey'], clean it, then echo the cleaned input as the returned data above.

If this information doesn't help you it's because you were too obtuse in your question.

Comment: No it pretty well sums it up. I was just really hoping to keep the entire cleaning process on one page but if there's no way to wait for the post-JS version there's not much more that can be done than execute the JS side after it's it's retrieved.. really I can convert what PHP does to JS functions, I was just hoping to keep it nice and neat in one place.

Comment: You could totally keep everything client-side and just attach an event listener to a submit button or something to execute your cleaning function(s) without even having to touch the server. In fact, I would recommend it if you already need JS on your page.

Comment: Looks like that's what will have to happen. Really the PHP just preps the code for JS and replaces some problematic Word characters (quotes, dashes, etc). I was just hoping I was *done* with the cleanup script and could force the requested page's JS to return with AJAX. All client-side it is.